# How to fix the error with a complex query EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core

I am writing a request

```
    var dish = _context.DishDbSet.Include(t => t.DishIngredient).
    ThenInclude(t=>t.Ingredient).
    ThenInclude(u=>u.BeneficialPropertiesIngredient).
    ToList();
```

In the answer I get incomplete data.
People tell me I have been sitting for 8 days in a row trying to figure it out, I myself am not working.
How can I get all the fields of the wired tables with values.

> here's the answer

```
 [{"id":1,
        "name":"Chicken with rice",
            "weight":10.4,
        "price":140.99,
        "image":"C:source",
        "dishIngredient":[{"ingredientId":1,
                    "ingredient":{"id":1,
                        "name":"Bow",
                        "protein":0.02,
                        "fat":0.52,
                        "carbohydrate":2.0,",
                        "dishIngredient":[



public class Ingredient
    {
        [Key]
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public decimal Protein { get; set; }
        public decimal Fat { get; set; }
        public decimal Carbohydrate { get; set; }
        public decimal Calories { get; set; }

        public ICollection<DishIngredient> DishIngredient { get; set; }
        public ICollection<BeneficialPropertiesIngredient> BeneficialPropertiesIngredient { get; set; }

    }


 public class Dish 
    {
        [Key]
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public decimal Weight { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
        public string Image { get; set; }

        public ICollection<DishIngredient> DishIngredient { get; set; }
        public Measurement Measurement { get; set; } 
    }



 public class DishIngredient 
    {

        public long IngredientId { get; set; }
        public Ingredient Ingredient { get; set; }

        public long DishId { get; set; }
        public Dish Dish { get; set; }
    }
```

Perhaps your experience will tell me what I can do to get all the data from nested tables.

Comment: That JSON looks truncated.  And, more generally, you'll need to post a complete repro, with all the classes that loads data and then queries it back.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft 
I did not quite understand what you meant, please explain with an example.

Comment: There's not enough information in your question to figure out what's going on.  Rework your code into a small, stand-alone program that demonstrates the issue, and you'll either figure out the problem yourself, or give other people enough information to help out.